# I changed struts and got alignment done, shop said steering is "returning from the right too fast"

Tags: toyota, steering, sienna, frontend

Vehicle is 2006 Toyota Sienna AWD.

I changed struts and sway bar link arms and then got alignment done, shop said steering is "returning from the right too fast." They said the alignment was all green, but maybe the ball joint castle nut was torqued too tight. I tried loosening the castle nut by one notch but this did not change anything.

What can I adjust to fix this? Do I need ball joints?

Comment: I'm not seeing how the ball joint being too tight would cause this ... never experienced it myself. Did the shop actually give you a print out of the alignment? I'm wondering if they screwed something up and didn't realize it.

Comment: Maybe the tech didn't know which nut was which? No pun intended!

Comment: I actually tried 2 different shops. First shop (Pep Boys) blamed the tires (which are almost new) and swapped them around. Then took it to a more traditional shop and they told me it was returning too fast. I'm still baffled as to what is going on, but a friend told me a lot of Sienna's have issues with front end.

Comment: By returns too fast, do you mean the number of turns to get to center(wheels in straight ahead) or when turned completely to the right, hands let go of steering wheel it turns its self straight while sitting still.

Answer (score 2):

I'd try a different front end shop and have it re-aligned. The steer return rate is affected by the caster and camber adjustments of the front end and by caster and camber that is the forward trajectory  ( Caster ) and the side to side ( camber ) settings on the front wheels. Maybe you just got a bad front-end man. If the problem isn't too bothersome I'd also recommend driving for some time and note the tread wear of the front tires that will tell a good story of what's happening . Pick up any automotive repair manual and it will explain about caster camber adjustments as well as the toe settings and the effect they have on the drivability of a vehicle. Good Luck.

Comment: I tried 2 different shops for alignment, both said it read "green" and couldn't get it to stop turning left. We traded it in for another vehicle and it's someone else's problem now.